# Jenkins says: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 while trying to list jenkins jobs on slack using hubot

Tags: jenkins, networking, devops, slack, hubot

I wanted to have a bot integrated with slack, using which my team can run Jenkins builds. I tried doing it using hubot, following the steps here: https://slack.dev/hubot-slack/

I mentioned all the variables (jenkins_url, jenkins auth -username:password, slack token) in .bashrc and sourced it. The bot connected to slack and when run `@hunot help`, it will list all the options. So far so good.

I also included jenkins.coffee script in hubot-scripts.json, to reach jenkins however, I'm unable to connect to jenkins. When I run `@hubot help`, it lists jenkins commands as well. The problem arises when I actually run one of those jenkins commands. When I run `@hubot jenkins list`, it returns `Jenkins says: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

I'm not sure what the issue is. On my jenkins host, I'm using nginx, reverse proxy (so that I don't have to use 8080 in url while accessing jenkins). Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Also, how can I access jenkins without user and password?